# Delayer persistent message store spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I'm implementing a Delayer which will check for an incoming message in regular intervals after which it will be routed to an error channel.
I understand that the Delayer picks up messages from the MessageStore and replays once the specified delay interval is done.

What if there is a scenario where there were messages in the MessageStore and the system went down? Possible loss of messages in volatile MessageStore? 
I read that there can be a persistent MessageStore tied to the Delayer help recover from such failures. Does Spring do this for you? or you need to explicitly configure the JDBCMessageStore.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/src/reference/asciidoc/delayer.adoc

Answer (score 1):

There is no any assumption of the target application environment, that's why we don't provide any persistent `MessageStore` by default. Only a simple in-memory full functional `MessageStore`.

You just should to choose a [sufficient](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-store) implementation and inject into your `Delayer` bean definition.

Comment: Can you share some light into how the Delayer works with a persistent message store? All messages are persisted. On system shutdown and failure which ones are picked up? All? Is there a mechanism similar to the normal message store where it removes all messages it processes?

Comment: M-m-m. How about if you read Reference Manual first http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#delayer-message-store ? And only after that come for some clarification. If that, of course...